# C++ read file until '%' character

Tags: c++

I am writing a program in which I am getting input form a text file. I want to read the file until I found this '%'. Currently, the `break` statement is not working and I am reading in the entire text file.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {


     char data[1000]; 
     char c = '%';
     int securitykey = 0;

    ifstream file("data.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {

        for(int i = 0; i <= 493; ++i)
        {
            if(data[i]==c)break;

            file >> data[i];
            cout<< data[i];
          securitykey += (int)data[i]; 

        }
         cout <<securitykey;
    }
}
```

input file :

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s
%152365
```

What I want is to read file until `%`.

Comment: What are the problems you are facing?

Comment: The break statement is not working and it is reading the complete text file

Comment: Next time, you should mention the problem in your question, I edited it in this time.

Comment: In addition to the obvious thing, I think there is another non-obvious reason why this won't work. `basic_istream::operator>>` does _not_ have an overload for `char`. It has overloads for signed and unsigned `short`, `int`, `float`, even `bool` -- but not `char`. So, this is bound to do something weird. Actually, I wonder what...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you check `data[i]` before reading data into it. Just put `if` check after the `file >> data[i]`:

```
file >> data[i];

if (data[i] == c)
    break;

cout << data[i];
```

Comment: Now it not reading only % sign and continuous reading after the % sign. I want it to stop when % sign is found.

Comment: @ZainabZainab I don't quite understand. Could you add example of the input file and the output of the program to your question?

Comment: you can see example in my question

Comment: @ZainabZainab What does your program prints to the output on this input file?

Comment: I just wanted to separate the key which is after % sign i dont want to print the key

Comment: @ZainabZainab So do you want to read file and print it out until `%` and stop, or you want to read number after `%` as well?

Answer (score 1):

You check `data[i]` before it's initialized. Local variables, including arrays, are not initialized, their value is *indeterminate* (and will seem random), reading from an uninitialized local variable leads to *undefined behavior*.

What you need to do is to read data first, *then* check if the character was what you were looking for.

Comment: Now it not reading only % sign and continuous reading after the % sign. I want it to stop when % sign is found.

Comment: @ZainabZainab Then there's something else you're not telling us.

Comment: Now i have added the text file in my question

Comment: @ZainabZainab I still fail to see how it should not work, if you just switch the place of the reading and the check. Can you also please edit your question to include the updated code and the actual output you get from the code?

Answer (score 0):

Switch the two lines:

```
if(data[i]==c)break;
file >> data[i];
```

To

```
file >> data[i];
if(data[i]==c)break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the line

```
if(data[i]==c)break;
```

What is at `data[i]`? Right now that will result in [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can fix this by doing two things. Firstly, when you create the array, zero it out so that it will be full of null characters (no more UB!)

```
char data[1000] = {0}; //fill data with 0's
```

Then, in your loop, read the next character into a temp variable, and check the temp variable. Your issue is that you check before you read:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 493; ++i)
{
    char temp;
    file >> temp;

    if(temp == c)break;       //If we found one, get out of there!

    data[i] = temp;           //If not, update data
    securitykey += (int)temp; //and security key 
}
```